# How can I use the Steam app to download a game I already own?

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

On the few occasions where I have bought a game on Steam from my mobile phone, the app gave me the option to start downloading and installing the game on my desktop. What I don't see, however, is any way to start downloading a game that I previously bought (in this case, a preorder for Saints Row IV) to my desktop.

Is there a way to remotely kick off a download for a previously purchased game through the app, or does the option only appear when completing a transaction?

Comment: It's a pre-order?  They generally won't let you download it 'til a day or two before the release date.

Comment: @Joe It is, but it released today. As such, I'd love to have it already downloaded by the time I get home from work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## App Instructions

On the left menu, click on your name to bring up your profile. Scroll down to your list of games and click "View All Games".

From here, it will list all games you own, whether or not they are installed, and include an icon that will allow you to install them remotely.

## Website Instructions

Go to your games list (accessible by going to your profile, then clicking Games), which will be at a URL like `steamcommunity.com/id/[YourID]/games/`.

From here, click on the "All Games" tab. This will show you which games you currently have installed, and will include an icon that will allow you to remotely install any games that are not installed.

Comment: You seem to be right, and I've found download buttons for various games on each of those pages. Strangely, Saints Row IV doesn't appear in my games list. Perhaps I'll check it later in case it's updating its database or something.

Comment: Probably just hasn't released yet; most Steam releases happen either in the morning, or around noon, based on Valve's time zone, which is Pacific time,

Comment: I'd like to add, that downloading is only possible if your computer is turned on, online and steam is running in online mode on it.

Comment: Seems like this feature has gone away, sadly.   I used to be able to install games remotely (say if I bought it on the website while at work, I can start the download so it's done when I Get home).   Now I can't find the install links anywhere.

Comment: @TM I can't find the link either. Kinda pissed. LMK if you figure it out.